# Play OpenAL source not from the beginning of the soundclip?

Tags: iphone, audio, delay, openal

It sounds easy, please let me know.

Have alSourcePlay(sourceID); any additional parameters?
Or something to set before send alSourcePlay?

I want to play it starting from various timecodes within the sopurce's length.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two seconds offset:

```
alSourcef(sourceID, AL_SEC_OFFSET, 2.0);
```

Thanks for me.